# Publishing high-volume metrics from Lambdas?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a bunch of Lambdas written in Go that produce certain events that are pushed out to various systems. I would like to publish metrics to CloudWatch that slice these by the event type. The volume is currently about 20000 events per second with peaks about twice that much.

Due to the load, I can't publish these metrics one-by-one on each Lambda invocation (each invocation produces a single event). What available approaches are there that cheap and don't hit any limits?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to utilize shutdown phase from lambda lifecycle to publish you metric.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html#runtimes-lifecycle-shutdown

To publish metric would suggest to utilize EMF(Embedded Metric Format) to combine multiple data points when calling PutMetricData API which takes also an array to act like a batch.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html